# How to install a downloaded .apk with React Native Expo?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I need to install downloaded `.apk` file from within the Expo app (it's for update functionality). This is my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button, View } from "react-native";
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";
import { startActivityAsync } from "expo-intent-launcher";

export function Updater() {
  async function updateApk() {
    const uri = "https://expo.dev/artifacts/eas/my_apk_name.apk";
    const localUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "test.apk";

    try {
      await FileSystem.downloadAsync(uri, localUri);

      await startActivityAsync("android.intent.action.INSTALL_PACKAGE", {
        data: localUri,
        flags: 1,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      alert(`Error during installing APK: ${error}`);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Reset APK" onPress={updateApk} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

It downloads the file, stores it, but then there is an error during `startActivityAsync`:

```
Encountered an exception while calling native method:
Exception occurred while executing exported method startActivity on module ExpoIntentLauncher:
file://data/user/0/com.my.app.id/files/test.apk exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

I tried passing uri first to `FileSystem.getContentUriAsync()` but then there is no error, the intent result is `0` but nothing happens.

My permissions in `app.json`:

```json
"permissions": [
   "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
   "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
   "CAMERA"
]
```

Do I need any additional permissions to get it to work? Or is it completely impossible with Expo? Maybe I should save the file to different location to be able to use this intent?

I also tried `android.intent.action.VIEW` with no luck.

I test it on Android 13, on physical device. App is built with EAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. The funny part is that I got the answer from the AI that is now banned here. But I just tested this solution on a real android device and it works. Anyway there are two changes needed:

1. `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` must be added to `app.json` file.
2. Uri for intent must be a content uri so: `localUri = await FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(localUri)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this command to build release build.

```
expo:build android
```

For that you have to signup in Expo's [website](https://expo.dev/).

After that you can get apk in Expo's server.

Comment: I use this command, the APK I'm downloading is already on their server. What I'm trying to do is to install it after downloading. It's possible from Xamarin as we have such solution in differrent project.